# webapp deployed twice and quartz job running twice

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I'm running a `quartz` job in my web application which is deployed in `tomcat`. But the problem is the job is executed twice.

After some internet research I've found that adding a new `Host` with `autoDeploy` in tomcat's `server.xml` may cause twice deployment. Which I guess is causing my `quartz` scheduler executed twice.

I tried with `autoDeploy = "false"`. But the problem continues.

Here is the host config in my **`server.xml`**:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
       pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>

<Host name="demo.example.com" appBase="webapps/demo" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
      <Context path="/" docBase="." reloadable="true" />
</Host>
```

Edit (FYI):
my cron expression: `0 50 12 * * ?` which is scheduled to run everyday at 12:50 pm.

Is this configuration will deploy my application twice? What can I do to avoid that? Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your observation is indeed correct then there could be multiple problems here -

1. In addition to custom location that you specified in server.xml, your app might be present in tomcat/webapps folder as well.
2. You might be using hot deployment from within some IDE and saving a file within IDE might be reloading the context, thus having quartz reinitialized again, which might be giving your wrong impression.
3. You indeed have some code problem.

It hard to say what's going on w/o looking at the code snippet but this should be fairly simple problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It was not 2/3. I was not using any IDE for deployment / didn't have any coding problem.
It was no 1. Apparently the application was within the webapps folder that's why it was deployed twice (as localhost & demo.example.com). I moved it outside the folder, changed the `appBase` & `docBase` and it worked.